# How can I enable all installed Gnome Shell Extensions?

Tags: gnome, ppa, gconf, extension

I need this, because sometimes the Gnome Shell "forgot" all my extensions configurations after a normal reboot/shutdown. And I'don't want reinstall entire system because this.

So I want a script or a command to enable then all during the my session startup (putting in gnome-session-properties) or even a fix for this problem.

I'm using Ubuntu Gnome 13.04 on Gnome Shell <s>3.8.3</s> (downgrade, now on **v3.6.3.1**)

Output of `find ~/ \! -user $USER -print`:

```
/home/mediacenter/.cache/dconf
find: `/home/mediacenter/.cache/dconf': Permission denied
/home/mediacenter/.gvfs
find: `/home/mediacenter/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

Comment: Sorry, what? If you are using the PPA, that is understandable. Since the PPA is unstable you should remove it and stick with the version in the Ubuntu repositories. The PPA could have unforeseen problems that would mess up your preferences. I'm using Gnome 3.6 without issues of this type.

Comment: I make a downgrade to Gnome 3.6 and **don't solve** the problem of 'forgot' configurations. But thanks for the enlightening, Braiam.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Can you provide the output of `find ~/ \! -user $USER -print`, if any? Edit your question if the output is positive.

Comment: Never had that problem with my Gnome-shell 3.8 (ubuntu 13.04 x64), but two days ago I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 RC  and Gnome-Shell 3.10 and now I have this problem that drives me crazy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To activate/enable all extensions every time at startup:

1. Create a folder for your own scripts:

   `mkdir ~/bin`
2. Create a script file: **gnome-shell-enable-all-extensions.sh**:

   `nano ~/bin/gnome-shell-enable-all-extensions.sh`

   With contents:

   `#!/bin/bash
   sleep 2s # just in case
   cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
   array=($(ls -l --time-style=long-iso | egrep '^d' | awk '{print $8}')) # get only the folder names from current path
   ext_list=$(printf "'%s',"  "${array[@]}") # rebuild the string
   ext_list=${ext_list%,} # Remove the final character of the variable
   gsettings set org.gnome.shell enabled-extensions "[${ext_list}]"`
3. Setting up permissions for the script file:

   `chmod +x ~/bin/gnome-shell-enable-all-extensions.sh`
4. At last, puts the command in startup `gnome-session-properties`:

   `/home/YOUR-USERNAME/bin/gnome-shell-enable-all-extensions.sh`

Comment: I still believe that is not a normal situation and your preferences shouldn't be forgotten... but ok.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, there is already a bug report about this here - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell/+bug/1236749

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but I implemented a solution script in python if the one above don't satisfy you.

https://github.com/loric-/enableGnomeExtensions.py

Hope that the problem will be fixed soon by the way.